# Clever way to get days between two dates with daylight saving in PySpark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, datediff

I need to calculate the difference in days between two timestamps of a PySpark DataFrame. Usually the difference between the timestamps should be full days but as the dates include daylight saving, sometimes the difference could be +/- one day. What would be a clever way to prevent that difference?

```
ID  start.                 stop                   days_between
A   2020-10-30 00:53:21    2020-11-28 23:53:21    29
B   2020-11-28 23:53:21    2020-12-28 23:53:21    30
```

The desired output would consider the daylight saving and look like the following

```
ID  start.                 stop                   days_between
A   2020-10-30 00:53:21    2020-11-28 23:53:21    30
B   2020-11-28 23:53:21    2020-12-28 23:53:21    30
```

What I'm calculating to far is:

```
df = df.withColumn('days_between',
                     func.datediff(col("stop"),
                     col("start")))
```

Is there a clever solution to that problem? Or do I simply add 1h to each timestamp that is between `xxxx-10-31 00:00:00` and `xxxx-03-26 23:59:59` of each year?

Comment: if you want to include daylight saving time, you need to use timezones. The timezone will be different for winter or summer time and converting these times back to UTC will give you the exact amount of time.

Comment: converting both start and stop using `func.from_utc_timestamp()` with the corresponding timezone solved the problem. Thanks @Steven